# When using hook_FORMID_form_alter(), how does one use validation to prevent form submission?

Tags: 6, forms, hooks

Here is the code I have, and while the errors do print to screen, the form will submit anyway. How do I prevent the form from finishing submitting?

```
function my_module_my_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // calls a function during validation
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_validate_address_check';
}

function my_module_validate_address_check(&$form, &$form_state){
    if($form_state['values']['panes']['delivery']['delivery_postal_code'] != 91006){
         drupal_set_message(t('Wrong Zip'), 'error');
        $return = FALSE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `form_error($form['delivery_postal_code'], $message)` instead of calling `drupal_set_message()`.

OR try

form_set_error('delivery_postal_code', $message);

Comment: This is throwing an error `Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: Oh sorry it should be reference to field, I have updated in the answer

Comment: It should be exactly as you defined it in the form.

Comment: hmm, now it's throwing this error: warning: `implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/myhome/htdocs/includes/form.inc on line 843.`

Comment: I'm sorry Shoaib, I'm a totally noob to drupal. What should be exactly as I defined in the form?

Comment: Can you show how are you defining your form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1578/discussion-between-shoaib-nawaz-and-kylex)

Comment: See my answer for next update

Comment: The `form_set_error('delivery_postal_code', $message);` worked. I couldn't get the other form_error to work though, even after I correctly identified the full form post element. Thank you!